# How to check if a query process is finished in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase. So pardon if this question makes no sense. I have experience only working with parse. In firebase how to check if a query process is finished ?.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the code that you're working with?

Comment: Please edit your question and add what Doug asked for and please also respond with @.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `AysncTask` in firebase to perform other operation after the query is performed. Please take a look here in documentation [AysncTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/services/concurrency/AsyncTask)

Comment: My requirement is that I have to run another task after this query has finished. So is there any way like a function which gets executed after the query

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all considering some firebase operations are asynchronous